# Radio button selection change not getting reflected in asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code ascx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="grdType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="lblright"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Primary" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Linked" Value="L"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updgrd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelPrimary" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelLinked" runat="server" Visible="false">
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
    if (UserRoleCondition)
    {
          grdType.Items[1].Selected = true;
          grdType.Items[0].Text = "A";
          grdType.Items[1].Text = "B";
    }
}
```

The layout of the page is such that on the right side is a grid view which is written in another user control. Left side is the user control with the above. codes. The grid view contains a list of different users some of whom satisfies the UserRoleCondition.

**Requirement**
When I select a user from the grid view

1. if he satisfies the UserRoleCondition, the labels for the radio buttons should be 'A' and 'B'. Also, the default selection should be 'B'
2. if he does not satisfy the UserRoleCondition, the radio buttons should be invisible.
3. If the user manually changes selection between the 2 radio buttons, the visibility of the corresponding panel will be toggled. ie if the first radio button is selected, then PanelPrimary should be shown and vice versa

**Problem**

Step A: During the first-page load, the first user is selected. If he satisfies the UserRoleCondition, the selection of radio button changes to B and the corresponding panel is shown. Now if I change this selection to A, the panel visibility is toggled and PanelPrimary is shown. (This step works as required)

Step B: After this step, I change selection to a different user in grid view who satisfies the UserRoleCondition

> The radio button selection stays in A instead of changing back to B.
>   It seems as though `grdType.Items[1].Selected = true;` does not work
>   at this moment.

Again, if I follow step A and then select a user from grid view who does not satisfy the UserRoleCondition as required the radio button disappears. Later if I follow Step B the radio button selection shows in B and everything works as expected.

I know this is a bit confusing. I just don't understand why the selection does not change. This is a high priority too.

Comment: Why do you do this in `Page_Load` and not in the appropriate events, f.e. `grdType_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: The  requirement is to change the labels and selection when the page loads.